# ViewPager returning empty array

Tags: firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

When I start my app I want my `customSwipeAdapter.java` to wait until my `savedImages ArrayList` has received and been populated with the data from firebase. But instead my class is being ran and my whole page is empty because `getCount()` method is returning `savedImages.size()` as 0 because my arraylist hasn't been populated in time. Any help on maybe running my class when my array list is populated. Not sure what to do here :)

customSwipeAdapter.java

```
    public class customSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

            private Firebase mRef;

            private Context ctx;
            private LayoutInflater layoutInflator;
            public customSwipeAdapter(Context ctx) {
                this.ctx = ctx;
            }

            private int[] frontImages = {R.drawable.amen_parham, R.drawable.janel_parham, R.drawable.kevin_parham};

            // Populate ArrayList with firebase data
            List<String> savedImages = new ArrayList<String>();

            Boolean goingToCallOnce = false;
            Boolean finishedLoadingData = false;

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return savedImages.size();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
                return (view == o);
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

                getSavedImages_FromDB();

                layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View item_view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);

                final EasyFlipView mYourFlipView = (EasyFlipView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.flipView);

                ImageView imageView_Front = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_Front);
                imageView_Front.setImageResource(frontImages[position]);

                container.addView(item_view);

                System.out.println(savedImages);

                return item_view;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
            }

            public void getSavedImages_FromDB() {
                mRef = new Firebase("");

                if (goingToCallOnce == false) {
                   goingToCallOnce = true;
                mRef.child("Q6i3fI6lNdYYS0z5Jty4WUYE9g13").child("SavedImages").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    String savedImage = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Image").getValue();

                        savedImages.add(0, savedImage);

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

        mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                finishedLoadingData = true;
                System.out.println("finishedLoadingData");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

savedCardsViewController.java

```
public class savedCardsViewController extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Swipe swipe;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    customSwipeAdapter adapter;

    private Firebase mRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved_cards_view_controller);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        adapter = new customSwipeAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new DefaultTransformer());

    }
}
```

['Context' to 'ValueEventListener'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfjTE.png)

[2'nd 'Context' to 'ValueEventListener'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDgjp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you load the data from Firebase on your Activity first and then pass it as a parameter to the adapter's constructor. This way your `CustomSwipeAdapter` would look similar to this:

```
public class customSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

            private Firebase mRef;

            private Context ctx;
            private LayoutInflater layoutInflator;
            List<String> savedImages = new ArrayList<String>();
            public customSwipeAdapter(Context ctx, List<String> savedImages){
                this.ctx = ctx;
                this.savedImages = savedImages
            }
            ...
            }
```

Another note on Loading data from firebase on the Activity: use A SingleValueListener with an iterator instead of `onChildAdded`:

```
mRef.child("Q6i3fI6lNdYYS0z5Jty4WUYE9g13").child("SavedImages").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                Iterator<DataSnapshot> data = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                                while(data.hasNext())
                                {
                                    String savedImage = (String) data.next().child("Image").getValue();
                                    savedImages.add(0, savedImage);
                                }
                                //Data has finished loading. Load your adapter
                                adapter = new customSwipeAdapter(this, savedImages);
                                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                                viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new DefaultTransformer());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                        });
```

Comment: So just to clarify, what your saying is to grab my data inside my savedCardsViewController class and once the data has finished loading call my viewPager.setAdapter(adapter) and so on?

Comment: it wants me to change the 1'st parameter of method 'customSwipeAdapter' from 'Context' to 'ValueEventListener' but when I do the app crashes? I'll edit my question and give a link to picture above

Comment: It worked, i Just added (adapter = new customSwipeAdapter(this, savedImages);
                                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                                viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new DefaultTransformer());) in a separate method and called that method, thank you pal :)

Comment: I'm glad you managed to solve the problem from the previous comment by yourself. You are welcome :)

Comment: would you happen to know how i would update my view when a new savedImages is added?

Comment: Replace `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` with `addValueEventListener()`